# HTML grid numeric column border color

Tags: html, css, html-table, colors, border

I am dynamically adding grid rows in html . In grid there is one numeric column creating in following way

```html
var td4 = document.createElement('input');
                td4.type = "number";
                td4.value = "0";
                td4.id = "count_" + i + "_t";
                td4.onchange = function call(){CallNumberCheck(this);};             
                td4.min="1";
                td4.max="99";               
                td4.setAttribute("style", "font-size:15px;min-height:90px;width:100%;padding-left:25%;padding-top:28%;");
```

But Column border is not in black color and having light black. I tried by keeping 
border:1px solid black; but it is showing thick black color .
Pls see added image where count column border is not black same as other columns.

[image]

Comment: It is an input, you need to reset the border style.

Comment: can you suggest how ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Hello, to reset the input border style : input { border: 1px solid #000; } Thanks,Neha

Comment: just like @NehaSharma said, reset the border style to the style given to other elemnts .. your input has an inset border, not solid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this CSS :  `input { border: 1px solid #000; }`

Here is the working code:

https://codepen.io/NehhaSharma/pen/MWWOrpQ